# azure synapse - serverless sql pool databases not visible in data tab

Tags: azure-synapse

I cannot see the serverless sql pool datababases or tables on the data tab in synapse.
Dedicated sql pool & spark pool are visible.
Is this by design or am i missing something?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the Databases tree after those new databases have been created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes, it's by design.

Under Data Tab you can browse `Dedicated SQL pools` and `Spark pools`.

[image]